# Adding ngDisabled inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to "overload" all inputs in my application. And in doing so, I'd also like to have ngDisabled used based upon a flag in the directive's scope.

Here's what I got and where I'm stuck is getting the ng-disabled to work on the element. I'm guessing I need to re-compile the element or something after I modify it? I'm also calling the directive by using the object notation:

```
angular.module("MimosaApp").directive({
    "textarea": appInputs,
    "input": appInputs
});

var appInputs = function($compile, Device) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        priority: 101,
        template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.attr("ng-disabled", 'isDisabled');
            return tElement;
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $compile(element);
            element.on("focus", function() {
                console.log($scope);
            })
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.isDisabled = true;
            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
};
```

What I'm seeing is... nothing is disabled even though I set isDisabled to true in the scope. What am I missing?

## Update 1

Ok, so maybe I do need to clarify it a bit. When a user interacts with an input of some kind, I currently have a message being sent back to the server and then sent out to all the other connected clients. This way the user's view changes based upon another user's interactions.

To take advantage of Angular better, I was thinking of trying to use the angular ngDisabled directive. When a user focuses an element, other users would see the element get disabled.

I currently keep track of a 'global' UI state on the server and send this JSON object out to the clients which then update themselves. So I was hoping to have elements get disabled (or other CSS classes) based upon a scope flag (Or other behavior). Something like `$scope.fieldsDisabled[fieldName]` and set it to true/false.

Maybe I'm thinking about it wrong by going the directive way.

This making any sense? haha

Comment: WHat happens if you just put `ng-disabled="isDisabled"` on the element itself. I dont think you would need to recompile it at all. You do not have a template and you are targeting form elements and you dont create scope as well. So they will just work as is.

Comment: Don't you need to add `ngDisabled` as a requirement (just like you did for `ngModel`)?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding `ng-disabled` to every input tag in this application as every element is going to need something like this. I'd prefer to avoid adding it by hand to every input, select, textarea in all the views.

Comment: @Charlie i don't really understand when you try to do `$scope.isDisabled = true;` what if you have multiple input elements sharing the same scope. You are going to set for all (or rather it is going to disable all)? Also what if this directive pollutes the actual scope by adding these properties (remember you are not creating any scopes)?

Comment: You're right PSL. I'm trying to make each input/textarea/whatever have its own scope that can keep track of its state (focus/blur/disabled) but a Service will be interacting with them. I figured step one would be to get a directive working on everything and I'm finding directives challenging. :/

Comment: The code you have should just work (disabling it).. Which version of angular you are using (Any errors in the console). I'd suggest, instead of getting it to just work you should think through on how useful this directive can be. Also your directive will be configurable if you let user specify `ngDisabled` in the directive and if you want to modify internally to set disabled or enabled based on specific logic you could as well do `$parse(attrs.ngDisabled).assign($scope, true);` in your directive.

Comment: I think if you provide more context in the question probably it would make more sense..

Answer (score 1):

In the directive life cycle `template` function gets called before compile so ideally it should work fine because you are setting the attribute inside template function. Can you try changing the attribute inside the compile function. Something like this.

```
var appInputs = function($compile, Device) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        priority: 101,
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            tElement.attr("ng-disabled", 'isDisabled');

            return function($scope, element, attrs) {
               element.on("focus", function() {
                console.log($scope);
               });
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.isDisabled = true;
            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this and sadly, nothing is disabled. I'm seeing the `ng-disabled` attribute showing up in the Dom but it doesn't seem angular is doing recognizing it?